# How to refresh current tab content on click of home menu in Electron JS using tab-group

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am new to Electron JS. I just created an application which use 2 tab and both tabs open a new url. In Menu I have a Home Button. On click of home, I need to hit the main url of that tab.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Dummy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <tab-group new-tab-button="true" sortable="true"></tab-group>

<script src="../node_modules/electron-tabs/dist/electron-tabs.js"></script>
<script>
  const tabGroup = document.querySelector("tab-group");

  tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "Google",
    src: "https://www.google.com/",
    active: true,  
    closable : false,
  });  

  tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "Amazon",
    src: "https://amazon.com/"  ,
    closable : false,
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const { Console } = require('console');
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

app.disableHardwareAcceleration();
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disable-software-rasterizer");

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {

  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 600,
    useContentSize:true,
    webPreferences: {
      webviewTag: true,  
    },
  });

  // custom menu and their event
  let menuTemplate = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [
            { label: "Close",
          click:function(){
            app.exit(0);
          }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        label : "Home",
        click:function(){
          mainWindow.reload();
        }
      }  
  ];

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  //load the custom menu
  let menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};


// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

if I am on amazon tab and I search something in amazon. On click of Home, it should load the amazon home url